# .ipa file doesn't get information from App Group

Tags: ios, xcode, widget, ipa, ios-app-group

I have an app that shares its data with a widget through app groups. It works fine in Xcode. However, when creating an ipa file and installing it, I am unable to get any data and the widget is just empty. Except for the widget issue, the app works 100% fine. How can I make app groups work within an ipa file?

To create the ipa file, I build my app, put the .app file in a folder named Payload, zip it and change the extension to .ipa. I do not have a paid developer account.

The widget displayed on my phone is empty but it shouldn't.

Comment: I use app groups extensively, I've never encountered any difference between running in Xcode or an ipa, nor can I think of any reason why they should be. Therefore perhaps the problem is not with app groups but the fact when you run in Xcode it's a debug build, and your ipa is ? presumably release build. Debug versus Release is an area for lots of potential for bugs and differences. Whenever you have issues like this the way to solve it is always always the same, put in lots of logging, look at the log output in the app, then in the ipa and look for differences

Comment: Okay, I understand. When creating the .ipa, how can I create it for debug mode?

Comment: And where can I see the log for the ipa?

Comment: I would try and build and run your app in Xcode in release mode to see if release mode causes any issues, that can be done by changing the Build Configuration in the Run Scheme to Release. You can see logs for an ipa by installing it and attaching the iPhone and launching the console and viewing the iPhone handset logs, but I'm talking about looking at your app's log output. If you don't have any logging in your app add some

Comment: So if I run my ipa on my phone while being plugged in my pc, I will get its output on the Xcode console right?

Comment: No, you'll see the app's logging in the Xcode console if you're running the app using Xcode. Otherwise you need to view the logging in the Mac's Console app